# How to replace in Python missing positional args with some predefined variable

Tags: python, arguments, args

I want to make this code runable with one, or two positional args:({host} and {port}) when you don't define port number it will replace with predefined number.

It works ok if you run code as >myurl.py localhost "" , but I would like to run like >myurl.py localhost or >myurl.py localhost 1234

How to avoid error message:

TypeError: url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'

```
import sys
def url(host, port):
    if port == "":
       sel_port = 5432 # set default port
    else:
       sel_port = port # set custom port
    gen_url = f'http://{host}:{sel_port}/'
    print(gen_url)

url(sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set default values in function params - e.g.:

```
def url(host, port=5432):
```

Comment: Thank you! It really works

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that error when I run your code, I get `IndexError: list index out of range` when trying to reference `sys.argv[2]`

This is a possible solution:

```py
import sys
def url(host, port=5432):
    gen_url = f'http://{host}:{port}/'
    print(gen_url)

url(*sys.argv[1:3])
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect!